# Highlight a value that contains multiple values in that single cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to highlight cells that has multiple values,

so the formula that i have right now is this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxzO7.jpg
[image]

it will highlight value that contain orange or blackcurrant.

the conditional formatting formula is this (I apply it to cell B3 to B6):

=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(IF($G$3:$G$4<>"",$G$3:$G$4),B3)))>0

---

What I want to do, is to highlight the cells that have multiple values, for example:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/AsHsphM.jpg]

It could highlight a cell that contains orange and blackcurrant. so its like custom filter like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9QCS.jpg
[image]

, but it's for conditional formatting, that way, i could just make a list of things that i want to highlight and i don't need to filter it one by one.

Is it possible to do this with conditional formatting?

Thank you,

Comment: Will you only have two values you want the condition to look for?

Comment: Yes, only 2 values because i want the function to be just like this custom filter. https://i.imgur.com/05wbn9W.jpg.

The value that I will input later is going to be like this, https://i.imgur.com/vUdQ7up.jpg 

value 2 is only "bla" and not blackcurrant because later I will deal with words like (for example): blacrrnt, blacrrant, blackcurrnt, blakccurant.
those kinds of typo words need to be highlighted too, so, the formula needs to have a "contain" feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look if this helps you.

```
=ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH($G$3,B3)*SEARCH($H$3,B3)))
```

[image]

Comment: You're the best Viki, this formula could save a lot of hours. Thank you so much Viki :)